# Keep db column comment when renaming a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

When I add a new column, I can add a db comment as follows.

```
add_column :foo_tables, :bar_column, :boolean, comment: 'comment'
```

However, when I change column name, the comment is gone and it seems there is no way to add it again...
I tried following patterns, but none of them worked :(

```
# migration succeeds, but comment is gone
rename_column :foo_tables, :bar_column, :bar_new_column

# migration fails (rename_column does not take :comment as arg)
rename_column :foo_tables, :bar_column, :bar_new_column, comment: 'comment'

# migration fails (change_column does not take :comment as arg)
rename_column :foo_tables, :bar_column, :bar_new_column
change_column :foo_tables, comment: 'new_comment'
```

Is there any way to keep comment after renaming a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change the bottom portion of your code to:

```
rename_column :foo_tables, :bar_column, :bar_new_column
change_column :foo_tables, :bar_new_column, :string, comment: 'new_comment'
```

If you look at the [migration](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) docs you can see that `rename_column` takes only 3 arguments:

> rename_column(table_name, column_name, new_column_name)

In your migration you can rename the column and then add the comment.

Comment: Thank you. I think you meant
`change_column :foo_tables, :bar_new_column, comment: 'new_comment'`,
but either way it didn't work...
I get `undefined method 'to_sym' for {:comment=>"new_comment"}:Hash` error.

Comment: Yeah you are right. What exactly did work? The comment didn't save?

Comment: I tried the updated answer, and it works like a charm! I really appreciate your help :)